# Separation of variables: when to have exponential solution and when sinusoidal?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In separation of variables, one can assume a solution of V(x,y) = X(x)Y(y) and after plugging this into Laplace's equation which is: ${{\partial^2 V} \over {\partial x^2}}$ + ${{\partial^2 V} \over {\partial y^2}}$ = 0 we can get:

${d^2X \over dx^2}$ = ${k^2X}$ which gives a solution ${X(x) = Ae^{kx} - Be^{-kx}}$?

and

${d^2Y \over dy^2}$ = ${-k^2Y}$ which gives solution ${Y(y) = C\sin(ky) - D\cos(ky)}$

(where k is some constant) However, I can't understand, why does positive ${k^2}$ give a solution with exponents and ${-k^2}$ has sinusoidal solution? Is it always so?

The book that I am referencing this from is Griffith 3rd edition of "Intro to Electrodynamics". He does mention this there: *"If X were sinusoidal, we could never arrange for it to go to zero at infinity, and if Y were exponential we could not make it vanish at both zero and a."*

But I don't quite see this? Also, the image used is: 
[image]

Ps: I'm sorry if this has been asked before on this site. If it has, could someone please direct me to the answer, since I could not find it?

Comment: FYI, there's also Physics Stack Exchange which may be more suited for such questions in the future.

Comment: @Semiclassical This could also fit here on Math SE as well because the question itself (why does this DE yield a sinusoidal or a exponential solution) is of mathematical nature.

Comment: @glace: Right. Should have just said that that place is _also_ suited for such questions.

Comment: Oh I see! I'll keep that in mind for any future questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you solve the differential equation $\frac{d^2 X}{dx^2} - k^2 X = 0$, then let $X=e^{mx}$ so that you get the auxiliary equation $m^2-k^2=0$. That auxiliary equation has roots $m_1=k,m_2=-k$, which are *real*. If you plug the roots to the formula
$$y=A e^{m_1 x}+ B e^{m_2 x}$$ you will get a solution with exponents.

If you solve the differential equation $\frac{d^2 X}{dy^2} + k^2 X = 0$, then let $X=e^{my}$ so that you get the auxiliary equation $m^2+k^2=0$. That auxiliary equation has roots $m_3=ki,m_4=-ki$, which are *imaginary*. If you plug the roots to the formula
$$y=C e^{m_3 x}+ D e^{m_4 x}$$ you will get a sinusoidal solution.

Comment: This makes sense! I will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: Yes, those signs will always give those answers. One can check that by direct differentiation. (There's also a physics way to say it: Suppose you had a particle subject to a force which is always directed away from $x=0$. Will the particle oscillate in its position, or will it keep moving away?)

That implies that, as long as $k\neq 0$, one of $X$ or $Y$ will have real exponential solutions and the other sinusoidal. Which goes with which? Recall that sinusoidal functions are periodic, and so can't vanish at infinity. Is this suitable for $Y(y)$?

Comment: Sorry, commenting again. Thank you, this makes sense; I think I got it. I see  that since Y is going from 0 to a, we need a periodic function and since the plates are infinite they need to "go to zero at infinity"   as we move farther from the vertical V_o potential. Thanks! :)